# Does anyone know why my thumbnail image is not showing?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong that my thumbnail image is not showing. I know this may be very basic but I am just a beginner and I keep deleting and changing stuff in the code and I still don't understand why it won't show. Thank you for your time and here is my code:

```css
h1,
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

max-width: 960px;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-gap: 8px;

}
.box img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 139, 186, 0.815);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Gallery heading</h1>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box"> <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="box"> <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  
  <p>.</p>
</body>
</main>
```

Comment: Both your HTML and your CSS have problems. Your HTML has invalid element nesting, and your CSS has orphan rules. I suggest formatting them properly so that's more apparent, and then run them through a validator. I'm not sure any of that is related to your problem, though.

Comment: Is your placeholder-image.png in the same folder as html?

Comment: As you can see, after I converted your code to a demo snippet it seems to work fine. It's either an image path issue, as Beller suggests, or something we can't see. Look at your browser's developer console. Also be sure to put as much effort into your writing (English) as your code. Your volunteer helpers and colleagues will appreciate it.

Comment: @isherwood your edit killed the problem.... How are people supposed to see the url when you changed it

Comment: Well, if the problem was image path we can't help anyway (or it's a hundredfold duplicate).

Comment: Edits should not alter code....

Comment: here in my browser it's working well, test your image path

Comment: they changed my entire code when they edited it..what is the point

Comment: i have the image in the same folder i don't understand what i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Your code css/html worked perfectly for me.